# Need help understanding how these two statements are equal

Tags: swift

Here is a block of code that is equivalent (to my knowledge) to the other.

`let f:()->() = brick`

where brick is

`func brick()->Void{ print("Throw Brick");}`

but I can also write it as

`let f = {return brick()}`

What is this ^ code doing.

The first code I know makes sense to me.  This is where I am defining a variable who's type is of the signature ()->() or ()->Void.  And then passing the reference of brick function to the variable.

Thanks

Comment: Are aware of the [closure](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html) syntax?

Comment: sort of but i might need refreshing. The book I'm reading mentioned it but I need to be reminded.  I know it has something to do with being able to omit certain things to simplify code

Comment: Actually they are not identical. The first f is brick. The second one is a function that calls brick. As for the syntax see http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch02.html#_anonymous_functions

Answer (score 2):

Though in both code snippets, `f` will behave in the same way when you call it, the code snippets are semantically different.

```
let f:()->() = brick
```

This assigns the function `brick` to the `let` constant `f`. Note that the type annotation is not required since the compiler knows that `brick` is a function that takes no parameters and returns `Void`, so it can infer that `f` must also be such a function too. Therefore, you can write it as:

```
let f = brick
```

Another way to write functions is to use a [closure expression](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html#ID95). For example, the following closure expression represents a function that calls `brick`:

```
{ return brick() }
```

Since you omitted the `in` keyword and didn't use any shorthand argument names (`$0`, `$1` etc), the compiler infers that the closure expression takes no arguments. And since `brick()` returns `Void`, the closure expression returns `Void` too - `return brick()` means "return what `brick()` returns". The compiler is able to infer the type of the closure expression, so this is valid:

```
let f = { return brick() }
```

This assigns a "closure expression that calls simply calls `brick()` and returns what it returns" to `f`.

Depending on how you look at it, this is a *bit* different from `let f = brick`, where you are directly assigning `brick` to `f`. But in the end, in both cases calling `f` will do the same thing - you will end up calling `brick`.

The difference is sort of similar to the difference between `let x: Double = 1` and `let x = cos(0)` - x = 1 in both cases, but one of those ways is more direct.

Answer (score 2):

First of all your two versions are not equivalent. This:

```
func brick()->Void{ print("Throw Brick");}
let f = {return brick()}
```

is equated by this:

```
func brick()->Void{ print("Throw Brick");}
func brickCaller() { return brick() }
let f = brickCaller
```

Whereas, the equivalent of your

```
let f:()->() = brick
func brick()->Void{ print("Throw Brick");}
```

would be simply

```
let f:()->() = { print("Throw Brick") }
```

with no intermediary call to `brick` at all.

So, anyway, I'd put it differently from Sweeper's answer. I'd reply that a function can be declared-with-a-name, using `func`, or be nameless (anonymous), using a mere function body.

So the point is that in each pair of equivalents, one function has a name-and-declaration of its own, with `func`, and the other function doesn't — its body is simply assigned directly to the variable `f`.

Comment: oh that makes a lot of sense.  Why would you call a function through another function rather than just calling it directly .  Also I'm reading your book and its awesome btw

Comment: But perhaps my book is not clear enough on the fact that an anonymous function can be assigned to a variable.

Comment: I think what confused me is the simplified syntax of an anonymous function.  Its soo simplified that I forget how it got there in the first place

Comment: Yes, an anonymous function, like any function, is in Swift a “first class citizen”. It can be assigned to a variable (as here) or passed as a parameter or returned from a function.